# Building java project with gradle

Tags: java, spring

I am following this tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/ . 
I did everything until the part where I need to add the following line to build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

When I run `gradle tasks` in cmd I get the following error :

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.java']`> org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectInternal".
```

I couldn't find an answer online .

Comment: post your build file

Comment: I said exactly whats it's name and it has that single line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I put build.gradle content into settings.gradle by mistake...